# why does JSON.stringify() adds extra ' ' around the object

Tags: javascript, json

what I understand that JSON format is similar as objects in JavaScript just keys are represented as string , hence:

```
{name:'John'}  \\is JavaScript object 
{"name":"John"} \\is Json
```

however when i try this

```
`var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
 var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);`
```

I get `'{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}'`
why this extra ' ' warping around the object?

Comment: The function is "stringify", hence it is making a string. The double quotes are used within the JSON, so single quotes are around it to make it a string. Any single quotes within the JSON will be escaped.

Comment: That's because `JSON.stringify` returns a string. If you try to console.log it, you won't see the `'`

Comment: Those just indicate that you're looking at a string. JSON is a string

Comment: It's not actually *inside* the string though, the string starts with `{` and ends with `}`

Answer (score 4):

There is no extra `'` wrapping the object (not that it is an object, it is a JSON representation of an object).

```js
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
var textNode = document.createTextNode(myJSON);
document.body.appendChild(textNode);
```

You might be using a debugging tool that is using `'` characters to inform you that the value of `myJSON` is a *string* (because that's the point of `JSON.stringify`: It takes a JS variable and makes a JSON text out of it, then it stores that text in a string and makes it available to JS).